# Why i cannot get deviceToken for push notfication apns?

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

it is my code of AllDelegate.swift

```
    @UIApplicationMain
    class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {   
        var window: UIWindow?
        var settings: UIUserNotificationSettings?     
        func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
            settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil)
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(settings!)
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()
            return true
        }
        .
.
.
.
.
.
.

        func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRomoteNotificationWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData){

            print("Got token data! \(deviceToken)")


            let characterSet: NSCharacterSet = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "<>")
            let DeviveTokenString: String = (deviceToken.description as NSString)
                .stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(characterSet)
                .stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "") as String


            let pushBadge = settings!.types.contains(.Badge) ? "enabled" : "dissable"
            let pushAlert = settings!.types.contains(.Alert) ? "enabled" : "dissable"
            let pushSound = settings!.types.contains(.Sound) ? "enabled" : "dissable"

            let myDevice = UIDevice();
            let deviceName = myDevice.name
            let deviceModel = myDevice.model
            let systemVersion = myDevice.systemVersion
            let deviceId = myDevice.identifierForVendor!.UUIDString


            var appName:String?
            if let appDisplayName =
                NSBundle.mainBundle().objectForInfoDictionaryKey("CFBundleDisplayName"){
                appName = appDisplayName as? String
            } else {
                appName = NSBundle.mainBundle().objectForInfoDictionaryKey("CFBudleName")
                    as? String
            }

            let appVersion
                = NSBundle.mainBundle().objectForInfoDictionaryKey("CFBudleVersion") as? String

            let myUrl = NSURL(string: "http://rb.cafe/api/apns.php");
            let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:myUrl!);
            request.HTTPMethod = "POST";


            let PostString = "task=register&appame=\(appName!)&appversion=\(appVersion!)&deviceuid=\(deviceId)&devicetoken=\(DeviveTokenString)&devicename=\(deviceName)&devicemodel=\(deviceModel)&deviceversion=\(systemVersion)&pushbadge=\(pushBadge)&pushalert\(pushAlert)&pushound=\(pushSound)"

            request.HTTPBody = PostString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);


            let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request){
                data, response, error in

                if error != nil{
                    print("error\(error)")
                    return
                }

                let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                print ("response \(responseString!)")
            }

            task.resume()

        }

        func application(applicatio:UIApplication, didFailToRegisterFoRemoteNoticationWithError error: NSError){

            print("Error to got data! \(error)")

        }

        func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveForRomoteNotificationWithDeviceToken userInfo: [NSObject: AnyObject]){      
            print("Detail! \(userInfo)")        
        }     
    }
```

i think proble with read

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRomoteNotificationWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData)
```

and i get this from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aOVn4kuQC6Y&list=PLdW9lrB9HDw0YBnnRIc0UeysAcuF73mGm&index=10

Comment: 2 Typo (one letter missing, one wrong) : `didRegisterForR-O-moteNotification-S-With...` Use always code completion to avoid those annoying errors.

Comment: i fix it, but again i cannot print deviceToken

Comment: 1) have you enabled the app for push notifications in the Apple portal? 2) Is the app using those profiles you enabled for push in the portal? 3) If yes and yes then have you got wifi turned on or a sim inserted? 4) what is the error code/message in didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotifications?

Comment: I think you should check your provisioning to see if it's configured correctly.